# Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'. > Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: build, build.gradle, keystore, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

MacOS using VSCode executed: flutter build appbundle

I have previously published Flutter to android on another project without a problem (pre null safety).

I created a new keystore for this App. When I got this message I tried using the keystore from my App that is published to Android, no difference. I created a new keystore, no difference.

I have read all of the like errors solution and no change in results for me.

The maker of flutter_mailer says it is not from his software.

Tried to build as an APK instead of APPBUNDLE. the Java message warning disappears but the "app:validateSigningRelease" is still there so it will not build.

I tried from the internet: “flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64”. No Java error but here is still the “app:validateSigningRelease” error, so no build.

```
result:
Note: /Users/administrator/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_mailer-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/dataxad/flutter_mailer/FlutterMailerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file not set for signing config release                      
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 52s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        53.6s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

```
storePassword=xxxx1234
keyPassword=xxxx1234
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/Administrator/upload-keystore.jks
```

```
*build.gradle:*
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.geoffreylefavi.EasyList_Pro"
        minSdkVersion 23     //changed from 16, 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried:
flutter build appbundle --debug --verbose
I do not see and error message at the end of the report.
No "release" file at [project]/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab
There is no release folder

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I misspelled key.properties.

Sorry about taking up so much space.